# Blue Prism Work Queue Collection

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I want to copy data from Work Queue Collection to the excel sheet without using "Utility-Collection manipulation" VBO. The problem is every time when i try to update next record it keep overwriting the excel sheet data.

Comment: Do you have all necessary data in collection? What actions are you using to copy data to excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MS Excel VBO object select action for finding last empty cell then go to that cell and in next action write the data what you need